# gwt createing date object from string?

Tags: gwt

I'm using a motionchart in a gwt appliation. My question is how to create a Date object from a string? Following is my code:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.DataTable;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.VisualizationUtils;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.LineChart;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.MotionChart;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.MotionChart.Options;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable.ColumnType;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat;

import component.client.SQLRunner;
import component.client.SQLRunnerAsync;

public class DashboardWidget 
{
    private HorizontalPanel containerPanel=null;
    private DataTable data=null;

    public DashboardWidget()
    {
        containerPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
    }
    public HorizontalPanel getContainerPanel()
    {
        SQLRunnerAsync service = (SQLRunnerAsync) GWT.create(SQLRunner.class);
        AsyncCallback<ArrayList<String[]>> callback = new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<String[]>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) 
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final ArrayList<String[]> result)
            {
                Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() 
                {
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        DataTable data = DataTable.create();
                        data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, " Name");
                        data.addColumn(ColumnType.DATE, "Date");
                        data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Count");
                        data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Something");
                        data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Something Else");

                        data.addRows(result.size());

                        @**SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                        Date date = new Date(1888,06,01);
                        DateTimeFormat fmt = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy,MM,dd");**

                        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++)
                        {
                            String[] temp = result.get(i);
                            String name=temp[0];//name
                            String count= temp[2];
                            String something=temp[3];
                            String seomthingElse=temp[5];


                            data.setValue(i, 0, name);//NAME
                            data.setValue(i, 1, date);//date
                            data.setValue(i, 2, Integer.parseInt(count));//eloc
                            data.setValue(i, 3, Integer.parseInt(something));//warning
                            data.setValue(i, 4, Integer.parseInt(somethingeElse));//static (open) warning   
                        }

                        Options options = Options.create();
                        options.setWidth(1000);
                        options.setHeight(1000);

                        MotionChart chart = new MotionChart(data, options);
                        containerPanel.add(chart);
                    }
                };
                VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, MotionChart.PACKAGE);               
            }
        };
        service.getDataFromDatabase("","","","", callback);
        return containerPanel;
    }
}
```

So How Do I create a date object from String for a GWT application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not use the DateTimeFormat object? Something like this:

```
Date parsed = fmt.parse(text);
```

Comment: Treid this:  String d = "10/10/2011";
DateTimeFormat fmt = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy,MM,dd");
Date date2=fmt.parse(d); but getting Illegal argument exception fro parse. what should be the format of the date string?

Comment: I would concur with Colin's suggestion, using the DateTimeFormat object is the preferred way to parse a String to a java.util.Date object. The DateTimeFormat to use, would be the one found in the package: com.google.gwt.i18n.client.

Comment: @sarah I guess replacing the commas (,) with forward slashes (/) would make sense, since the date is separated by slashes?

Comment: 10/10/2011 is not in yyyy,MM,dd format. Instead, try MM/dd/yyyy format to read that string.